# How to sort Months & Years in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table with date field and converting into Months and Years (2 separate columns). I am not able to sort:

```
Month    Year
12        2011
11        2011
2         2012
1         2012
```

If I write the query, it gives as

```
  Month       Year
   1          2012
   2          2012
   11         2011
   12         2011
```

However I need like below

```
  Month          Year
   11         2011
   12         2011
    1         2012
    2         2012
```

Here group by Month, I don't want to display date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what you can do:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY MONTH) RN
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT * FROM CTE  
ORDER BY YEAR, RN
```

> [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9afc/5)
>
> Actually one more staright forward way would be to,

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select datepart(month, DateCol) as [Month],
       datepart(year, DateCol) as [Year]
from YourTable
order by [Year], [Month]
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4279d/1)

And if you want to group by month

```
select datepart(month, DateCol) as [Month],
       datepart(year, DateCol) as [Year]
from YourTable
group by datepart(month, DateCol),
         datepart(year, DateCol)
order by [Year], [Month]
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af9bd/2)